# How to take a PickleType data and convert to csv files in a folder using Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pickle

I am trying to take a `PickleType` data from `sqlalchemy` and converted it to csv files in a folder.

Here is a snip of my class with the `PickleType` data:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import PickleType 
Base = declarative_base()

class Sales(Base):
    .....
    data = Column(PickleType, nullable=False, comment="Sale Data for sale")
```

Here is my function that I am trying to get that data in `PickleType` and convert it to CSV files in a folder

```
from data import Sales
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import pickle

def _to_csv(self, sales_data : Sales):
    """
    To get Sales data to output CSV files into a folder
    """
    data1 = []
    with open(sales_data.data, 'rb') as file:
        data2 = pickle.dumps(file)
        data1 = pickle.load(data2)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
        df.to_csv(os.path.join('/Desktop/sales','/car_sales.csv'))
        file.close()
```

Comment: do you have a problem that needs to be solved or are you looking for improvements like performance gain or parallelization or etc?

Comment: @Dariyoush looking for improvement if this function works for setting data to a csv files into a directory with performance gain will be perfect!

Comment: ok, so you pass different data into the `_to_csv` function, right? say sth like data1, data2, ...  and you call the function many times to save them in. is this the case?

Comment: Yes that’s correct, pass different data and this function gets called as many times to save them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your class and data but if you have the data you can just append them into a list and give call your `_to_csv` method in parallel to save it for you. sth like this:

```py
from data import Sales
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import pickle
import multiprocessing as mp
import concurrent.futures


def _to_csv(self, data):
    """
    To get Sales data to output CSV files into a folder
    """
    data1 = []
    with open(data 'rb') as file:
        data2 = pickle.dumps(file)
        data1 = pickle.load(data2)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
        df.to_csv(os.path.join('/Desktop/sales',f'/{data}.csv'))
        file.close()

# I am assuming that you have the name of the files that you wanna read and save as cvs
data_list = []
for idx in range(20):
    name = f'car_sales{idx}'
    data_list.append(name)    

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=mp.cpu_count()) as executor:
    executor.map(_to_csv, data_list)
```

or if you want to assign each data name to its result you can do sth like this:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=mp.cpu_count()) as executor:
    futures ={executor.submit(_to_csv, data):data for data in data_list}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        data = futures[future]
        try:
            result = future.result()
        except Exception as why:
            print('sth went wrong!', why)
        else:
            print(data, result)
```

Comment: Thank you @Dariyoush, that looks great yeah for the name of the file I am thinking to increment as it process the file like file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv …. my class doesn’t have a name to the file.  For this increment to happen I need another loop prob?

Comment: glad to help. yes, that's how I built data_list for example. you can do the same or sth like that.